# Finiteness of a set and axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This can be thought of as a continuation of the post [Hermis14](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4318960/334795), which deals with sets of specific structures. Now, the last question that remains to me is when the finiteness of a set really matters.

For nonempty sets $A$ and $B$, consider a surjection $ f: A \to B $.

Consider the sentences:

- $S1$: $B$ is finite.
- $S2$: $B$ is infinite.
- $S3$: There is a function $g: B \to A $ such that $ \forall y \in B: f(g(y)) = y $.

I think both claims $ S1 \to S3$ and $ S2 \to S3 $ require the axiom of choice because though we know that the fiber $f^{-1}[y]$ for each $y \in B$ is nonempty, a specific choice rule cannot be considered since $f$ is unknown.

But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) says that

> In many cases, such a selection can be made without invoking the axiom
> of choice; this is, in particular, the case if the number of sets is
> finite, or if a selection rule is available

Does it mean that $S1 \to S3$ does not invoke the axiom of choice? Would you help me figure out what I am missing?

Comment: AC asserts the *existence* of a "choice set"; thus, if we have a finite number od finite sets, we may simply list them: $A_1= \{ a,b,c \}, A_2= \{ e,f,g \}, A_3= \{l,m,n \}$ and "legislate" that the choice set is $S = \{ a,f,n \}$. No further condition is needed, because $\{ A_1,A_2,A_3 \}$ is a collection of nonempty sets and $S= (x_i)$ is such that $x_i \in A_i$ for every $i$.

Comment: The same for an infinite collection of infinite sets: $A_1= \{2,4,8,\ldots \}, A_2 = \{ 3,9,27, \ldots \}, A_3 = \{ 5, 25, 125, \ldots \}$ because we have a "rule" that describes them and thus we can always specify the "choice set" with a "derived rule": pick the first one for every set: $S = \{ 2,3,5,\ldots \}$.

Comment: In your example, we have that $B$ is finite and thus we can list it: $B = \{ b_1, \ldots, b_n \}$. But how to define $g$? We have that in order to specify $g = \{ (b_1,a_1), \ldots, (b_n, a_n) \}$ we need a rule to pick the $a_i$ (that for sure exist) ...